# Blocking write operation on OutputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

Communication between two servers:

Server 1 sends a request to Server 2
Server 2 writes response on the stream by using below api

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(servResp.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(dataObj)
```

When server 1 receives the data as

```
InputStream res = connection.getInputStream();
if(res.available() > 0) {
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(res);
    Object object = ois.readObject();
    dataObj = (DataObject)object;
}
```

Here, res.isavailable() returns zero bytes, It will be resolved by using blocking read on Server 2, But Is there any way to handle it on Server 1?

Comment: Server 2 isn't doing a read in the code you've given.. your question is unclear. But fundamentally, using `available()` is almost *always* a mistake.

Comment: Don't call `available`. If you know that an object will be sent, just call `readObject`. That will block until the data has arrived.

Comment: My question is when Server 2 executes res.available() It should returns number of bytes in the stream. Is it possible?

Comment: res.available() returns the number of bytes available to read without blocking. Unless the stream is already completely buffered (i.e. has been transmitted, has somehow already made it into the InputStream's buffer and is very short) this will not show the number of bytes in the stream.

Comment: @mreaevnia You need to read the Javadoc. There is a specific warning there *against* using it as though it gave the number of bytes in the stream. It doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Any implementation of `available()` is free to return zero, and there is nothing in the Javadoc about it returning the number of bytes in the stream: on the contrary, there is a specific *denial* that it does any such thing. Your receiver should just *block* in `readObject()`. There is nothing that the sender can do to help other than send.

Comment: ObjectInputStream#available's implementation is quite complex, so I guess if there is data available, it will return something other than 0. But, yeah, you should never need to call that.